# Get Value from Object using another value

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is silly but I can't figure it out.

I have a simple object in JS:

```
var objSyntax = [ {"a": "1"},
                  {"b":  "2" },
                  {"c":  "3"} ];
```

I want to call 1 when `theid` is equal a, etc.

Here is the notation I tried which did not work:

```
objSyntax[theid];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have an Array of Objects. You'll need to iterate the Array, and test each Object to see if it has the `"a"` key. Or if the keys are guaranteed to be unique, you should probably make a single Object `var objSyntax = {"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could change your object to reflect something like:

```
var objSyntax = {"a": "1",
                  "b":  "2" ,
                  "c":  "3"};
objSyntax[theId];
```

or iterate through the array of objects you have posted:

```
var objSyntax = [ {"a": "1"},
                  {"b":  "2" },
                  {"c":  "3"} ];
```

Comment: Perfect! Your first solution worked great, and it's much simpler than the second option. Thanks!

Comment: Of course, you have an array of objects and not an object as you claim in your question.

Answer (score -1):

With how you have it set up right now, you would access it like this

```
objSyntax[0][theId]
```

Comment: That will only work if `theId` contains `a`. If it's `b` he needs to do `objSyntax[1][theId]`, and so on.